# How to switch two rows in a matrix in scheme or haskell?

Tags: haskell, scheme

I was trying to do this after I did the transpose  of a matrix using the map function but still can't figure out how to swap two rows in a matrix.
I'm a beginner in functional programming and trying to learn.
This is my code for transpose :

```
transpose ::[[Int]]->[[Int]]
transpose([]:_)=[]
transpose x = ((map head x):(transpose (map tail x)))
```

And I want to do something similiar to this:
Switch/swap two rows of a matrix

```
[[1,2,3]         [[4,5,6]
 [4,5,6]    =>    [1,2,3]
 [7,8,9]]         [7,8,9]]
```

Comment: You might wanna spend a couple more minutes to clarify your question; As it stands it's not very clear what exactly you're trying to do (of course it has something to do with matrices, but for example you didn't even mention how you define a matrix - and I'd be very interested to see how you defined transpose with map, that sounds kinda odd - transpose is a structural operation, wheras map only exposes contained values).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Please post some code from your best attempt. This will make your question a better fit for the site and you will be likely to get better answers in return.

Comment: i edited the question and included an example of what i want and code from transpose

Comment: You should definitely use the approach in mhwombat's answer, but another option would be to multiply by the appropriate [elementary matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Ah, you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. I'm going to assume you always want to swap the first two rows. How would you do it if it were a simple list, e.g....

```
[a, b, c, d]    => [b, a, c, d]
```

You'd probably write something like this:

```
swapFirstTwo (a:b:xs) = b:a:xs
swapFirstTwo xs = xs           -- if there are <2 elements
```

If we load this into GHCi, we can ask what the type signature of `swapFirstTwo` is.

```
λ> :t swapFirstTwo
swapFirstTwo :: [a] -> [a]
```

So `swapFirstTwo` can take a list of *anything*. Can it handle a list of lists?

```
λ> swapFirstTwo [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
[[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[7,8,9]]
```

Yes it can!